# I am confused how to understand this code. contains double pointers

Tags: c, pointers, malloc

I don't understand why the code below changes the array `b`:

```
int a[] = { 3, 6, 9 };
int b[] = { 2, 4, 6, 8, 10 };
int **c;
int **d[2];
c = (int **)malloc (b[1] * sizeof(int *));
*c = &a[1];
c[1] = c[0] + 1;
*d = c;
c = c + 2;
*c = b;
c[1] = &c[0][3];
*(d + 1) = c;
d[0][3][1] = d[1][0][0];
d[1][0][2] = d[0][1][0];
```

I have run this code and found the values of array `a` and array `b` but I am unable to understand how these values come.

Array `a` remains unchanged while `b` becomes `2, 4, 9, 8, 2`. How does this happen?

```
c = (int**)malloc(b[1] * sizeof(int*));  //int **c[4] ???
```

`c` is an array of double pointers `*c = &a[1]` this means that `c[0]` has the address of array a's second index. I am not getting the way to interpret this.

Comment: Consider expanding this into a [mcve] and formatting it so it is readable.

Comment: `c` is a *pointer to pointer to `int`*, `malloc` allocates storage for `b[1]` (e.g. `4`) pointers. See: [Do I cast the result of malloc?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/995714). *"`c[0]` has the address of array `a`'s second index"* -- yes.

Comment: Could this be a homework assignment or exam question? I get the impression because of the typical non-commented, almost obfuscated, coding style, which is typically accompanied by a "Describe the effect of this code." instruction. In that case please consider the compromise described here https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions Even if not, please let us know your level of knowledge, by explaining as much of the code yourself as possible. Then the gaps can be filled in by an answer more efficiently.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code contains actual statements, therefore it must be part of a function body, hence all declarations herein have automatic storage. It is highly convoluted, with purposely contrived double indirections... Lets analyse it one line at a time:

- `int a[] = { 3, 6, 9 };` -- `a` is an array of 3 ints initialized with some explicit values.
- `int b[] = { 2, 4, 6, 8, 10 };` -- likewise, `b` is an array of 3 ints initialized with some explicit values.
- `int **c;` -- `c` is an uninitialized pointer to a pointer to `int`, that can be made to point to an array of pointers to `int`.
- `int **d[2];` -- `d` is an uninitialized array of 2 pointers to pointers to `int`, each of which can be made to point to an array of pointers to `int`.
- `c = (int **)malloc(b[1] * sizeof(int *));` -- `c` is set to point to a block of uninitialized memory with a size of `4` pointers to `int`. In short, `c` now points to an uninitialized array of `4` pointers to `int`.
- `*c = &a[1];` -- The element pointed to by `c` (aka `A[0]`) is set to point to the second element of `a` (aka `a[1]`, with a value of `6`). The value of `A[0]` is `&a[1]`.
- `c[1] = c[0] + 1;` -- The second element in the array pointed to by `c` (aka `A[1]`) is set to point to the element after the one pointed to by `c[0]`, hence it points to the third element of `a` (aka `a[2]` with a value of `9`). The value of `A[1] is`&a[2]`.
- `*d = c;` -- The first element of `d` is set to the value of pointer `c`, which is the address of `A[0]`. The value of `d[0]` is `&A[0]`.
- `c = c + 2;` -- The pointer `c` is incremented by `2`, it now points to the third element of the array `A` allocated with `malloc()`, `A[2]`.
- `*c = b;` -- The element pointed to by `c`, `A[2]`, which is itself a pointer, is set to point to the first element of `b`, `b[0]`. The value of `A[2]` is `&b[0]`.
- `c[1] = &c[0][3];` -- The element after that, A[3], the 4th element of the array allocated by `malloc`, is set to point to the 4th element of the array pointed to by the element `c` points to. `&c[0][3]` is equivalent to `c[0] + 3` or `&(*c)[3]` or simply `*c + 3`. This element is `b[3]` which has the value `8`. The value of `A[3] is`&b[3]`.
- `*(d + 1) = c;` -- This is equivalent to `d[1] = c;` which sets the second element of `d` to the value of the pointer `c`, which is the address of the 3rd element of the array allocated wth `malloc()`, `A[2]`, which points to `b[0]`. The value of `d[1]` is `&A[2]`.
- `d[0][3][1] = d[1][0][0];` -- Let's rewrite these terms:

  - `d[0][3][1]` => (&A[0])[3][1] => `A[3][1]` => `(&b[3])[1]` => `*((b + 3) + 1)` => `b[4]`
  - `d[1][0][0]` => `(&A[2])[0][0]` => `(*&A[2])[0]` => `A[2][0]` => `(&b[0])[0]` => `b[0]` which is the value `2`.
  - Hence `b[4] = 2;`.
- `d[1][0][2] = d[0][1][0];` -- Let's rewrite these:

  - `d[1][0][2]` => `(&A[2])[0][2]` => `(*&A[2])[2]` => `A[2][2]` => `(&b[0])[2]` => `(b + 0)[2]` => `b[2]`.
  - `d[0][1][0]` => `(&A[0])[1][0]`, ie `A[1][0]` => `(&a[2])[0]` => `*&a[2]` => `a[2]` that has a value of `9`.
  - Hence `b[2] = 9;`

As a consequence, the array `b` now has elements `{ 2, 4, 9, 8, 2 }`.

You can run the program:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    int a[] = { 3, 6, 9 };
    int b[] = { 2, 4, 6, 8, 10 };
    int **c;
    int **d[2];
    c = (int **)malloc (b[1] * sizeof(int *));
    *c = &a[1];
    c[1] = c[0] + 1;
    *d = c;
    c = c + 2;
    *c = b;
    c[1] = &c[0][3];
    *(d + 1) = c;
    d[0][3][1] = d[1][0][0];
    d[1][0][2] = d[0][1][0];

    printf("a = { ");
    for (size_t i = 0; i < sizeof a / sizeof *a; i++)
        printf("%d, ", a[i]);
    printf("};\n");

    printf("b = { ");
    for (size_t i = 0; i < sizeof b / sizeof *b; i++)
        printf("%d, ", b[i]);
    printf("};\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: No UB. `d[1][0][0]` is 1st element in `b`, `d[0][1][0]` is next address after `6` in `a` (e.g. the address of `9`).

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin: Yes, my mistake, such a waste of time and energy!

Comment: It's good to dust off the cobwebs. You did a good thing. The only reason I caught was I stepped through it with a debugger `:)`. `b` is `{ 2, 4, 9, 8, 2 };` at the end due to `d[0][3][1] = d[1][0][0];` -- `:)` (ducking)  Here is what I did [ptrfun.c](http://susepaste.org/84146148) - expires 7 days.